# AWS Route53 ConflictingDomainExists: is there is a way to associate the same VPC with multiple private hosted zones sharing the same parent domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

is there is a way to associate the same VPC with multiple private hosted zones that are sharing the same parent domain (for example : eu-central-1.amazonaws.com).

I've created the following two private hosted zones to share VPC Interface Endpoints between multiple account from a Centralized Account :

- **sqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com**
- **athena.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com**

when I try to associate the private hosted zones with the same VPC in the centralized account (in **eu-central-1** region) using terraform, I'm getting the following error message:

> Error: error creating Route53 Hosted Zone: ConflictingDomainExists:
> The VPC vpc-******** in region eu-central-1 has already been
> associated with the hosted zone Z0491******** with the same
> domain name.

as both of them are sharing the same parent domain (**eu-central-1.amazonaws.com**).

Unfortunately in this case it won't be possibile to create a parent domain with multiple subdomains.

anyone could help ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually it was my error
I tried to associate the same VPC with private hosted zones before disabiling private DNS naming for the VPC interface endpoints.

after disabilig it, everthing is working fine and I could be able to associate the VPC with the different private hosted zones